# Customize sharing URLs for embedded Youtube video

Tags: youtube-api, sharing

When you embed a Youtube video on a website the video can be shared by clicking the sharing icon located in the top right corner. The video can be shared to Facebook, Twitter and Google+

Is there a way to customize the shared URL so it is not a direct link to Youtube?